# why image cannot display

Tags: html, css

I want to put the transparent light image on background color for making a good effect

i don't know why the light image didn't display

its what i have done :

http://jsfiddle.net/4pbq2tx8/2/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<meta charset=utf-8>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

</head>
<body>

 <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/carousel.js"></script>
<div id="carousel">


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

css :

```
#carousel
{
border:solid 1px #1a1a1a;
position:relative;

width:922px;
height:221px;
margin:0 auto;
margin-top: 50px;
display: block;
background-image:url(light.jpg);
}
body
{
    background-color: #c7c7c7;

}
```

Comment: You din't included the image path. Where do you put the image?

Comment: perhaps he can't find the image

Comment: This will only work if the image Is in the css folder. If it is not there you need to change that path to the image..

Comment: in External Resources called light.jpg  and i called it in this line background-image:url(light.jpg);

Comment: yes he  is in folder of css and he didn't display please look in http://jsfiddle.net/4pbq2tx8/2/

Comment: Who is in the folder? You can't put images on jfiddle.net server, do you?

Comment: @user3778154 External resources is [only for css or js files](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html?highlight=external#external-resources).

Comment: This is the url of image http://s4.postimg.org/590qvkilp/light.png i was put it in External resources i don't know why it doesn't display

Comment: I added the url above and it worked: http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/4pbq2tx8/3/

Comment: @user3778154 I just told you why it won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25232766/why-image-cannot-display#comment39306512_25232766), the reason why your externally 'loaded' image is not showing up in your fiddle is because of the fact that [external resources are only for loading css or javascript files](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html?highlight=external#external-resources).

Indeed, this becomes obvious when inspecting the source of the included iframe:

[image: Image included as js file]

As the image is included in the page as a javascript file.  If the type is unknown(eg, not being css or javascript), the file is loaded as javascript, as noted in the previously linked documentation.

In order to properly load such an image, you need to supply the full url in the actual css of the fiddle.  Example:

```
#carousel
{
    border:solid 1px #1a1a1a;
    position:relative;

    width:922px;
    height:221px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: block;
    background-image:url('http://s4.postimg.org/590qvkilp/light.png');
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4pbq2tx8/8/)

Answer (score 0):

The external resource you included is loaded from **another website** `s4.postimg.org/590qvkilp/light.png`

[image: Screenshot from Chrome]

Because the image is not in the **same location** you need to include that full location.

```
background-image: url(http://s4.postimg.org/590qvkilp/light.png);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/4pbq2tx8/5/)** here

Comment: That's not why it isn't working, I guess I'll answer since my comment fell on deaf ears.

Comment: Please add an answer then. Looking forward to it.